# How to perform a Trie search using an autocompleteTextView in android?

Tags: java, android, autocompletetextview, trie

I need to implement an AutocompleteTextView with a Trie search. I am using a Vertex class and a Trie class for the Trie tree data structure and an adapter for customize the view of the dropdown box of the autocompleteTextView.

Here are all the classes I am using:

The Vertex class:

```
public class Vertex {

private HashMap<Character, Vertex> vertexSons;
private List<Integer> wordsIndexList;
private List<Integer> prefixesIndexList;
private int wordsNumber;
private int prefixesNumber;

public Vertex() {
    vertexSons = new HashMap<Character, Vertex>();
    wordsIndexList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    prefixesIndexList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    wordsNumber = 0;
    prefixesNumber = 0;
}

public boolean hasWords() {
    if (wordsNumber > 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean hasPrefixes() {
    if (prefixesNumber > 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public void addVertexSon(Character character) {
    vertexSons.put(character, new Vertex());
}

public void addIndexToWordsIndexList(int index) {
    wordsIndexList.add(index);
}

public void addIndexToPrefixesIndexList(int index) {
    prefixesIndexList.add(index);
}

public HashMap<Character, Vertex> getVertexSons() {
    return vertexSons;
}

public List<Integer> getWordsIndexList() {
    return wordsIndexList;
}

public List<Integer> getPrefixesIndexList() {
    return prefixesIndexList;
}

public int getWordsNumber() {
    return wordsNumber;
}

public int getPrefixesNumber() {
    return prefixesNumber;
}

public void increaseWordsNumber() {
    wordsNumber++;
}

public void increasePrefixesNumber() {
    prefixesNumber++;
}
}
```

The Trie class:

```
public class Trie {

private Vertex rootVertex;

public Trie(List<Trieable> objectList, Locale locale) {
    rootVertex = new Vertex();

    for (int i = 0; i<objectList.size(); i++) {
        String word = objectList.get(i).toString().toLowerCase(locale);
        addWord(rootVertex, word, i);
    }
}

public Vertex getRootVertex() {
    return rootVertex;
}

public void addWord(Vertex vertex, String word, int index) {
    if (word.isEmpty()) { 
        vertex.addIndexToWordsIndexList(index);
        vertex.increaseWordsNumber();
    }
    else {
        vertex.addIndexToPrefixesIndexList(index);
        vertex.increasePrefixesNumber();
        Character fChar = word.charAt(0);
        HashMap<Character, Vertex> vertexSons = vertex.getVertexSons();

        if (!vertexSons.containsKey(fChar)) {
            vertex.addVertexSon(fChar);
        }

        word = (word.length() == 1) ? "" : word.substring(1);
        addWord(vertexSons.get(fChar), word, index);
    }
}

public List<Integer> getWordsIndexes(Vertex vertex, String word) {
    if (word.isEmpty()) {
        return vertex.getWordsIndexList();
    }
    else {
        Character fChar = word.charAt(0);
        if (!(vertex.getVertexSons().containsKey(fChar))) {
            return null;
        }
        else {
            word = (word.length() == 1) ? "" : word.substring(1);
            return getWordsIndexes(vertex.getVertexSons().get(fChar), word);
        }
    }
}

public List<Integer> getPrefixesIndexes(Vertex vertex, String prefix) {
    if (prefix.isEmpty()) {
        return vertex.getWordsIndexList();
    }
    else {
        Character fChar = prefix.charAt(0);
        if (!(vertex.getVertexSons().containsKey(fChar))) {
            return null;
        }
        else {
            prefix = (prefix.length() == 1) ? "" : prefix.substring(1);
            return getWordsIndexes(vertex.getVertexSons().get(fChar), prefix);
        }
    }
}

}
```

The Adapter class:

```
public class MunicipalitySearchAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Municipality> {

private ArrayList<Municipality> municipalities;
private ArrayList<Municipality> allMunicipalities;
private ArrayList<Municipality> suggestedMunicipalities;

private List<Trieable> triableList;

private Trie municipalityTrie;

private int viewResourceId;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public MunicipalitySearchAdapter(Context context, int viewResourceId, ArrayList<Municipality> municipalities) {
    super(context, viewResourceId, municipalities);
    this.municipalities = municipalities;
    this.allMunicipalities = (ArrayList<Municipality>) this.municipalities.clone();
    this.suggestedMunicipalities = new ArrayList<Municipality>();
    this.viewResourceId = viewResourceId;
    this.triableList = new ArrayList<Trieable>();
    for (Municipality mun : allMunicipalities) {
        triableList.add(mun);
    }
    municipalityTrie = new Trie(triableList, Locale.ITALY);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(this.viewResourceId, null);
    }
    Municipality municipality = municipalities.get(position);
    if (municipality != null) {
        TextView munNameTxtView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView proSignTxtView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.sign);
        TextView regNameTxtView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.regionName);

        if (munNameTxtView != null) {
            munNameTxtView.setText(municipality.getName());
        }
        if (proSignTxtView != null) {
            proSignTxtView.setText(municipality.getProvinceSign());
        }
        if (regNameTxtView != null) {
            regNameTxtView.setText(municipality.getRegionName());
        }
    }
    return v;
}

@Override 
public Filter getFilter() {
    return municipalityFilter;
}

Filter municipalityFilter = new Filter() {



    @Override
    public String convertResultToString(Object resultValue) {
        String str = ((Municipality) (resultValue)).getName();
        return str;
    }

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

        if (constraint != null) {
            String constraintString = constraint.toString().trim();
            suggestedMunicipalities.clear();


            List<Integer> wordsIndexesList = municipalityTrie.getWordsIndexes(municipalityTrie.getRootVertex(), constraintString);
            for (int index : wordsIndexesList) {
                suggestedMunicipalities.add(allMunicipalities.get(index));
            }

            List<Integer> prefixesIndexesList = municipalityTrie.getPrefixesIndexes(municipalityTrie.getRootVertex(), constraintString);
            for (int index : prefixesIndexesList) {
                suggestedMunicipalities.add(allMunicipalities.get(index));
            }

            FilterResults filterRes = new FilterResults();
            filterRes.values = suggestedMunicipalities;
            filterRes.count = suggestedMunicipalities.size();
            return filterRes;
        }
        else {
            return new FilterResults();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            ArrayList<Municipality> filteredMunicipalities = (ArrayList<Municipality>) results.values;
            ArrayList<Municipality> supportMunicipalitiesList = new ArrayList<Municipality>();

            clear();
            for (Municipality mun : filteredMunicipalities) {
                supportMunicipalitiesList.add(mun);
            }
            Iterator<Municipality> municipalityIterator = supportMunicipalitiesList.iterator();
            while (municipalityIterator.hasNext()) {
                Municipality municipality = municipalityIterator.next();
                add(municipality);
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }           
    }
};
}
```

I get a null pointer at this line (in the Filter performFltering() method implementation inside of the adapter):

```
for (int index : wordsIndexesList) {
                suggestedMunicipalities.add(allMunicipalities.get(index));
            }
```

Do you have any possible solutions to the problem? I can't fix it out. What am I missing or mistaking?

EDIT: I have found the problem, I needed to set the constraint `toLowerCase()`. Now it works. However. Why do I see the autocomplete suggestions ONLY when I type the FULL word? (in my case the name of a municipality).

It seems that my Trie doesn't return the PrefixIndexes which I can use for populating the List of suggestions. But I can't find out the problem. Any idea?

Thanks again!

Comment: I think this old question is rather broad - it would require some debugging. I doubt you still need this, but is there a point where those prefixes can be printed out? I assume that the autocomplete generates an event when it wants to query the index?

Comment: @halfer I forgot this post, anyway I have resolved somehow in the past. I see a `close` vote, do I have to close this question?

Comment: I voted to close, but that's not binding. You do not have to close it, no - could you write an answer instead? I tend to believe that the price of asking for help is writing about the solution if you find it first.

Answer (score 0):

To fix typing of FULL word issue mentioned by the author, `getWordsIndexes` should be replaced by `getPrefixesIndexes`, and `getWordsIndexList` - by `getPrefixesIndexList` in `getPrefixesIndexes()` method of `Trie` class:

```
public List<Integer> getPrefixesIndexes(Vertex vertex, String prefix)
{
    if (prefix.isEmpty())
    {
        return vertex.getPrefixesIndexList();
    }
    else
    {
        Character fChar = prefix.charAt(0);
        if (!(vertex.getVertexSons().containsKey(fChar)))
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            prefix = (prefix.length() == 1) ? "" : prefix.substring(1);
            return getPrefixesIndexes(vertex.getVertexSons().get(fChar), prefix);
        }
    }
}
```